# Solving $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n$ by recurrence relations and characteristic polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution

How do I solve $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n$ by recurrence relations given $a_0=1$? I realize that it equals $n!$ by inspection, but how do I solve it as a first-order non-homogenous recurrence relation (with characteristic polynomials like in linear algebra)? I have tried to solve it like this:

$a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n$

$a_{n}=(n)a_{n-1}$

But it is not like adding a constant, in which I can just do this and subtract. Dividing is of no help either. How should I approach such a problem?

P. S. I have not learned differential equations, and don't wish to do algebra/function bash as in [Solving this non-homogenous recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469024/solving-this-non-homogenous-recurrence-relation/2469045#2469045).
This answer [Solving this non-homogenous recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469024/solving-this-non-homogenous-recurrence-relation/2469036#2469036) is too vague for me, and I don't know how to solve the equation using the method.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to prove this by induction?

Comment: It is for an assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach. Note that
$$
\begin{split}
a_n &= n a_{n-1}
     = n \left( (n-1) a_{n-2} \right) \\
    &= n (n-1) a_{n-2} \\
    &= n (n-1) (n-3) a_{n-2} \\
    & \ldots\\
    &= n \times \ldots \times (n - (n-1)) a_{n-(n-1)}\\
    &= a_1 \left(\prod_{k=1}^n k \right) \\
    &= a_1 \times n!
\end{split}
$$
and it's easy to show from the recurrence that since $a_0 = 1$ then $a_1 = 1$ as well.

---

Another approach is to substitute $a_n = b_n \cdot n!$ to get the recurrence
$$
b_{n+1} \cdot (n+1)! = a_{n+1} = (n+1) a_n = (n+1) \cdot n! \cdot b_n
$$
which is equivalent to $b_{n+1} = b_n$ which you can solve with usual methods to get $b_n \equiv 1$.

---

Last one, if you insist on doing this specifically using the characteristic polynomials, is to take logs in some convenient base, and let $b_n = \log (a_n)$ obtaining the recurrence
$$
b_{n+1} = b_n + \log (n+1)
$$
which you can try to solve using the usual methods.

Answer (score 3):

If we divide the equation
$$a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n\tag1$$
by $(n+1)!$ we get
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{a_n}{n!}.\tag2$$
Substituting $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n!}$ we get a homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients, namely
$$b_{n+1}=b_n.\tag3$$
The general solution of $(3)$ is
$$b_n=c\tag4$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. Hence the general solution of $(1)$ is
$$a_n=cn!.\tag5$$

Comment: But it required us to already know the answer to be a factorial. I want to assume that we know nothing about this function except the equation.

Comment: If you plug in $c=\frac{a_n}{n!}$ from the definition of $b_n$ you get the result